# What is the error in this MS-DOS bit?

Tags: batch-file

I'm making a DOS game, and the first thing to come up is the option to play the game or learn to play the game.  This is the code bit I believe is being weird:

```
SET /P startgame=Selection: 
if %startgame%=="how2play" goto how2play
if %startgame%=="play" goto play
if %startgame%=="" goto launch
goto codeerror
```

Here are the intended actions:
SET: User input of "play" or "how2play" it set to variable "startgame"
IF: "startgame" variable used to redirect user to "how2play" or "play"

Here is what happens instead:
Rather than havinng the intended outcome of either option, it goes straight to the failsafe, being "codeerror"

Notes:
In this bit, I did not include the "codeerror", "how2play", or "play" bits in this question, but if they are necessary to find an answer as to why the IF statements (I suppose) are not working, let me know.  "launch" is also included in this bit, however this code bit is part of the "launch" operation, the only thing missing from it is some text just printed onto the console using the "echo" command.

Comment: Try wrapping %startgame% with quotes in your IF statement (like: IF '%startgame%'=='play'). This sample should be helpful: http://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/362-batch-file-menu

Comment: The command line in Windows has nothing to do with MS-DOS.

Comment: To be fair, he may _actually_ be coding this in DOS for some reason. It's unlikely, but not impossible,

Comment: if it really were DOS, the question would be: "why doesn't set /p work"

Comment: Just needed to wrap %startgame% in quotes, Thanks